# Как работают методы в React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, AppRegistry, FlatList, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }
  _onload() {
    this.abc.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
          onScrollBeginDrag={this._onload}
          ref={(FlatList) => {this.abc = FlatList;}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => PizzaTranslator);
```

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrolltoend

Как  мне использовать метод scrollTo? как это вообще работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятен ваш пример. Как следует из [документации](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html), для реализации контейнера со скроллируемым контентом в react-native есть два компонента - **ScrollView** и **FlatList**. Первый отрисовывает сразу всех потомков *(что кстати очень негативно сказывается на производительности)*, второй же делает это "лениво", отрисовывая только тех, что находятся в области видимости.

Относительно методов, ScrollView имеет только **ScrollTo**, который принимает одним из аргументов координаты куда скроллировать, и **ScrollToEnd**, который, как следует из названия, скроллит до конца.
FlatList будет побогаче, он имеет четыре метода, о назначении которых не сложно догадаться из названия: **scrollToEnd, 
 scrollToIndex, scrollToItem, scrollToOffset**.

**scrollToIndex** заставляет контейнер проскроллить содержимое до определенного индекса по порядку.
**scrollToItem** заставляет контейнер проскроллить содержимое до определенного индекса по значению. Последний является более "тяжелым", документация рекомендует использовать скролл по индексу.

Рабочий пример c FlatList и scrollToEnd, 
 scrollToIndex, scrollToItem : https://snack.expo.io/H1bFiiJcf